# SharePoint Online - Can I use Azure AD and On premise at the same time for authentication

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, azure

I want to create external users in seperate domain in Azure AD.
The employees in our company are in On-premise AD.
Currently SharEPoint Online is authenticating with On-premise AD.
Can I use both authentication methods at the same time in SharEPoint Online and how do I do that?

Comment: I may not give you answer but need help from your question. I need integrate on premise AD to SharePoint online. so that my users will be authenticated with imported user id's. Please help me with procedure. Thanks in advance.
Sai

Comment: You have to use the directory synch tool to sync the accounts with office 365 and from there SharePoint online will pick it up. http://blogs.office.com/2014/04/15/synchronizing-your-directory-with-office-365-is-easy/  .  Let me know if you run into any issues with it.

Comment: With O365 online can we use both Azure AD and On-Premise AD at the same time. We can use sub-domain but not a separate domain to do this.
Thanks
Nate

Comment: Nate, I know this is almost 2 years old, but I'm looking to do pretty much the same setup (ADFS auth for internal users, Azure AD for external users) and was wondering if you could elaborate on the solution you reference in your comment above. Thanks.